# How can I add an additional tag on my question

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow

Recently I have posted a question with the tags 'cocoa' and 'macosx'.

Somewhat later I recognized that it would be a good idea to tag the question with 'xcode' additionally.

But there seems no way to add more tags once the question is posted.

Could someone give a hint to me howto achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Click "edit" (underneath your question's text, but above the comments and replies), and change the **Tags** field at the bottom of the page. Or point anyone here at your question.